# Excel formula to copy a column based on another column value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have 3 excel columns like this,

```
Col_A     Col_B     Col_C
-----     -----     -----
Ross      Joey    
Rachel
Monica    Chandler
          Pheobe
Gunther   Janice
          Carol
Susan     Richard
```

I want the values to be copied in Column C in the following condition,

1. If Col_B has value, then Col_C should have the same value as Col_B (Regardless of Col_A has value or not).
2. If Col_B is Blank, then Col_C should have the same value as Col_A.

So finally my Col_C will look like this,

```
Col_C
-----
Joey
Rachel
Chandler
Pheobe
Janice
Carol
Richard
```

Is there any excel formula using which I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below will work if the empty cells are indeed empty

`=IF(Col_B="",Col_A,Col_B)`

The below if the 'empty' cells have a space (this crops up more often than you'd think!)

`=IF(Col_B=" ",Col_A,Col_B)`

Comment: You could also use the TRIM function on your cell which would deal with multiple spaces.

Comment: What's `TRIM` and how do we use it? :)